# Timing Experiment - Matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, flops

> Determine a matrix size that you can comfortably fit into your
>   available RAM. For example, if you have a 4 GB machine, you should
>   be able to comfortably store a matrix that occupies about 800MB.
>   Store this value in a variable `Mb`. Use the following information to
>   compute a maximum matrix dimension N that you can store in Mb
>   megabytes of memory.
>
> - A megabyte has `1024` kilobytes
> - A kilobyte is `1024` bytes
> - A floating point number is `8 bytes`.
> - An `N × N` matrix contains `N^2` floating point numbers.
>
> Call the N you compute `nmax`.
>
> (b) Create two random matrices `A` and `B` each of size `Nmax × Nmax`.
>   Using the MATLAB functions `tic` and `toc`, determine how much time
>   (seconds) it takes to compute the product `AB`. Determine the number
>   of floating point operations (additions and multiplications) it takes
>   to compute the `Nmax × Nmax` matrix-matrix product `(2/3)n^3.` Use
>   this number to estimate the number of floating point operations per
>   second (’flops’) your computer can carry out. Call this flop rate
>   `flops`.

```
% Part A
nmax = sqrt((1600*1024*1024)/8); % 8GB of RAM

% Part B
A = (nmax:nmax);
B = (nmax:nmax);

tic 
prod = A*B;
prod_time = toc

flops = (2/3)*(prod).^3
```

Everything runs fine but I feel like I am not creating a matrix for the values `A` and `B`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two main things: you messed up your matrix assignment; `c:c` where `c` is a constant just returns the constant. The colon, `:`, creates *arrays*, such as

```
c = 5;
N = 1:c
    1  2  3  4  5
```

Feeding the colon operator the same start- and endpoint obviously just returns that point.

Second: the total number of operations was proportional to the *number of elements*, not the actual result of the matrix product (which is irrelevant actually, we're just interested in the time). So first calculate the total number of **FL**oating point **O**perations.

Remember that we used `tic/toc`? Well, perhaps we should find out what the total time was, which is stored in `prod_time`. This is the number of seconds it took to perform the matrix multiplication. Dividing `Totflops` by `prod_time` gives you the **FL**oating point **O**perations **P**er **S**econd, i.e. FLOPS.

---

```
[~,systemview] = memory; % Get RAM info
tmp = systemview.PhysicalMemory;
% tmp.Total stores the total system RAM

Mb = 0.2*((tmp.Total/(1024^2))); % 20% of the total RAM

% floor your nmax to force it to be integer
nmax = floor(sqrt((Mb*1024^2/8))); % create your nmax

A = rand(nmax); % random nmax x nmax matrix
B = rand(nmax); % random nmax x nmax matrix

tic
prod = A*B;
prod_time = toc;

% Total flops
Totflops = (2/3)*(nmax).^3;

flops = Totflops/prod_time; % flops/sec
```

Which on my system (8GB RAM and an i5 750 2.66GHz) gives `flops = 1.0617e+10`